# Reading numbers from file in Fortran, SIGSEGV error

Tags: fortran90

I'm trying to write a Fortran code for Lennard Jones potential and read coordinates from file [posinp_38.xyz](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02223153109961515043), but I encounter `SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred`
how can i found where is the problem. I'm new in Fortran, so any help is helpful.

```
    PROGRAM lennardjones_1
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL(8), allocatable :: rat(:,:) ! coordinates of atoms
REAL(8), allocatable :: fat(:,:) ! force between atoms
INTEGER :: nat                   ! number of atoms
!INTEGER :: iat, jat             ! loop counter
REAL :: epot                     ! potential energy
REAL :: ftot                     ! total force on atoms
CHARACTER(len=20) :: filename    ! Input data file name
CHARACTER(len=3)  :: sat         ! for reading the file
INTEGER :: status            ! I/O status: 0 for success


! Get the name of the file containing the input data.
WRITE (*,1000) 
1000 FORMAT (1X,'Enter the file name with the data to be sorted: ')
WRITE (*,*) 'The file name is: posinp_38.xyz or posinp_1000.xyz '
READ (*,'(A20)') filename

! Open input data file.  
OPEN ( UNIT=21, FILE=filename, status='OLD', ACTION='READ', &
       IOSTAT=status )
READ (21,*) nat
READ (21,*)

CALL force_energy(rat, nat)
    write (*,*) epot, ftot
END PROGRAM lennardjones_1

SUBROUTINE force_energy(rat,nat)
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL(8), allocatable    :: rat(:,:) 
REAL(8), allocatable    :: fat(:,:) 
INTEGER, INTENT(IN)     :: nat
INTEGER :: iat, jat     ! local variables
REAL    :: epot 
REAL    :: r , dx, dy, dz, d
REAL    :: ftot 
INTEGER :: status       ! I/O status: 0 for success
CHARACTER(len=3)  :: sat

allocate (rat(3,nat))
allocate (fat(3,nat))
! Was the OPEN successful? 
fileopen: IF ( status == 0 ) THEN       ! Open successful
    DO iat = 1, nat
        READ (21,*) sat, rat(1, iat), rat(2, iat), rat(3, iat)
    END DO
    CLOSE(21)
END if fileopen

DO iat = 1, nat 
    DO jat = iat+1, nat
        dx = rat(1,jat)-rat(1,iat)
        dy = rat(2,jat)-rat(2,iat)
        dz = rat(3,jat)-rat(3,iat)
        r  = sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)
        d = 4*(-12/r**14 + 6/r**8)
        fat(1,iat) = fat(1,iat) + d * dx 
        fat(2,iat) = fat(2,iat) + d * dy
        fat(3,iat) = fat(3,iat) + d * dz
        fat(1,jat) = fat(1,jat) - d * dx
        fat(2,jat) = fat(1,jat) - d * dy
        fat(3,jat) = fat(1,jat) - d * dz
        ftot = ftot + (fat(1,iat)**2+fat(2,iat)**2+fat(3,iat)**2)+ &
            (fat(1,jat)**2+fat(2,jat)**2+fat(3,jat)**2)
        epot = epot+4*(1/r**12-1/r**6)
    END DO
END DO
END SUBROUTINE force_energy
```

Comment: Do you know about using a debugger?  If this is on Linux or Unix, compile with with `-g` and run with `gdb`.

Comment: It's in Linux, about debuggers not ever. I google it.

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you got that code to compile.  You've defined a subroutine with an allocatable argument and not provided an explicit interface, a standard-compliant compiler should spot that and raise an error.  In fact, I'm so surprised I suspect you've not compiled the code posted and that the error stems from some completely different issue.

But, if that really is your code the easy way to fix the problem is to move the line

```
END PROGRAM lennardjones_1
```

to the end of the source file and, in the space it has vacated, insert the line

```
CONTAINS
```

Those changes will make the subroutine internal to the program and the compiler will take care of defining an explicit interface.

Once you've made those changes add `INTENT(OUT)` to the declaration of `rat` in the subroutine.

Comment: Nice to surprised you! :)